# Loopings over dataframe and saving into excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to loop over a dataframe and save each filter onto a different tab in an Excel document.  For some reason, I'm only getting the last loop saved onto the excel file. Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'Name':['John','Paul','Darren','John','Darren']})
names = ['John','Paul','Darren']


for k,v in enumerate(names):
    this_filter = df[df['Name'] == v]
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\somefilename.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
    this_filter.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = str(k),index = False)
    writer.save()
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a different writer object in each iteration, overwriting the previous one. You just need to move it out of the loop, close the writer at the end, and it should work fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number':pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]),'Name':pd.Series(['John','Paul','Darren','John','Darren'])})
names = ['John','Paul','Darren']

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\somefilename.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')


for k,v in enumerate(names):
    this_filter = df[df['Name'] == v]
    this_filter.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = str(k),index = False)
writer.close()
```